# After facebook login, retrieve facebook address of user?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to utilize facebook login for my website's alumni tracer. What I want to do now is to be able to retrieve the facebook profile address of a user, how can I do that? What I am planning to do is to list down all the names with a link such that when the link is clicked then it will go to the users profile.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can always just link to `www.facebook.com/{userid}`.

Or you could first check if the user has a username set [1], and then just link to `www.facebook.com/{username}` – if you want the links to look “prettier”. `www.facebook.com/zuck` maybe looks a little nicer then `www.facebook.com/4` – but the numeric id link will always automatically redirect to the version with the user name anyway.

[1] AFAIK everyone has a username set nowadays – if the user did not set one explicitly themself, Facebook makes one up out of their first name/last name compination.